# Sending SMS via Twilio POST error

Tags: angularjs, rest, post, sms, twilio

This comes after half a day of banging my head against the screen, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to send an SMS message via Twillio on a click-event. I'm using Angular, calling the SendTestMessage function on click. Unfortunately, I keep running into this error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/sendsms 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my controller:

```
  .controller('WhotoMessageCtrl', function($scope, UserService, $http, $q){
  console.log("whotomessage page");

  $scope.saveContactInfo = saveContactInfo;
  $scope.contact = {};
  $scope.sendTestMessage = sendTestMessage;

  function sendTestMessage(number){
    console.log('this fired', number);
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http({
        url: '/sendsms',
        method: 'POST', 
        data: JSON.stringify({number}),
        contentType: 'application/json',
      }).success(function (number){
        console.log('text has been sent to', number);
        defer.resolve(user);
      });
      return defer.promise;
  };
```

Here is my server side code:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method){
        return res.send(200);
    }
    next();
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

var sendSMS = function(to){
  var outgoing = {};
  outgoing.to = to;
  outgoing.from = '19725593683';
  outgoing.body = 'Your table is ready';

  client.messages.create(outgoing, function(error, message){
    if (error){console.log(error.message)}
  })
};



app.post('/sendsms', function(req, res){
  sendResponse(res, req.body.phoneNo, 201)
  sendSMS(req.body.phoneNo)
  res.end();
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, ignore the second app.use in server-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Twilio developer evangelist here.

It could have been that you forgot to copy bits of the code, but it seems `client` hasn't been defined, which means you aren't even making a request to Twilio.

The correct way to initialise `client` according to [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install) is:

```
// Your accountSid and authToken from twilio.com/user/account
var accountSid = '{{ account_sid }}';
var authToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
```

Only then you can on your code do:

```
var sendSMS = function(to){
  var outgoing = {};
  outgoing.to = to;
  outgoing.from = '19725593683';
  outgoing.body = 'Your table is ready';

  client.messages.create(outgoing, function(error, message){
    if (error){console.log(error.message)}
  })
};
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, Marcos! I've solved this problem and come across another!

Comment: @SamuelBowler did my answer help you? If so, please mark it as the correct answer and post a new question here.